# A question on Motor Sich of Ukraine

Tags: ukraine

- [Ukrainian Court Seizes Aerospace Company Motor Sich From Chinese Investors](https://www.rferl.org/a/ukraine-seizes-motor-sich/31161801.html)
- [Ukraine may sell 50% stake in Motor Sich to Turkish firm](https://www.dailysabah.com/business/defense/ukraine-may-sell-50-stake-in-motor-sich-to-turkish-firm-report)

I have two questions in this regard:

1. Is the decision of sanctioning the Chinese company from investing in Motor Sich influenced by US-Ukraine relations?
2. Why does Ukraine consider the Chinese acquisition of Motor Sich's share as "a matter of state security" while they are okay with the Turkish acquisition?

Comment: For all tensions, Turkey remains a NATO member. Not all foreign investments are equal.

Answer (score 3):

Your second source fails to provide with any proof, it does not even attempt to. Quoting it (highlight mine):

> Ukraine may sell a stake in engine-producing giant Motor Sich to a Turkish company, **a local news site** said, **citing sources**.

So, the article refers ["Chas News"](https://chas.news/), a third-grade news aggregator, and I failed to find a specific article on that site.

Now seriously. I did their job and found that no-name source. That poor site appeared to be "24 kanal" that has a long story of relations with Russian criminals/oligarchs and that played a significant role in today's war in Eastern Ukraine *(ask me for details)*.

Now, to the article. [Here's the link](https://24tv.ua/motor-sich-mozhna-prodati-zavod-turechchini_n1603285) (in Ukrainian). What do we see?

- first, it is a "blog post" by Andriy Voropayev, "a politologist". Sounds intriguing;
- secondly, the clog clearly says:

  > Окремий напрямок — пошук іноземного партнера, який би запропонував ринок, альтернативний китайському, для продукції "Мотор-Січі". **Таким наразі може бути тільки Туреччина**. Вона є членом НАТО і зацікавлена у технологіях МС. Вже лунала **інформація про можливі переговори** Зеленського та Ердогана із цього питання.

  A vague translation:

  > A separate direction is the lookup for a foreign partner who would offer an alternative to Chinese market, for Motor Sich products. At the moment, **it can only be Turkey**. It is a member of NATO and has an interest in Motor Sich's technologies. **We've heard the information on possible negotiations** between Zelensky and Erdogan on this issue.

So the author thinks that "only Turkey could be" the buyer because "we've heard the information" about the "possible" negotiations on President's level. **Wow. Very convincing, I would say.**

Other things to consider.

1. Selling the control stock of Motor Sich shares to Chinese clients has not been agreed with the Anti-Monopoly Committee of Ukraine.
2. So no, it was not sold to Chinese investors. The case is not closed.
3. Nor is Ukraine considering selling it to our Turkish partners (to the best of our knowledge).
4. The privatization of a large factory capable of producing military-grade products is not in interests of any country. The Motor Sich is no exception: [Secretary of State Pompeo: US wary of China’s attempt to buy Motor Sich](https://www.kyivpost.com/ukraine-politics/secretary-of-state-pompeo-u-s-wary-of-chinas-attempt-to-buy-motor-sich.html)
5. De-monopolization was one of the requirements our US/EU partners demand from Ukraine for decades.

---

## TL;DR

Carefully pick sources you read.